# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Gamma-distribution Scale parameter

Tags: plotting, fitting, random, distributions

I have the following tasks:

1. Generate random sample with given parameters shape = 2, scale = 0.001 and shape = 2, scale = 1/1200 for the right censored sample;
2. Using Maximum Likelihood Method estimate scale parameter and find the "accuracy" of this estimated value;
3. Show results in the form of graphs representing dependencies of the sample volumes towards estimation and accuracy of estimation of the scale parameter.

I don't understand how to calculate the "accuracy", may be it's called different, because I am not native English speaker.
And I don't know how to plot the results.
I hope someone could help me with this, btw I am totally new in Mathmatica, thanks.

The code:

```
MTTF = RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[2, 0.001], 100]
histMTTF = Histogram[MTTF, Automatic, "PDF"]
plotMTTF = Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[2, 0.001], x], {x, 0, 0.01}]
EstimatedDistribution[MTTF, GammaDistribution[a, b], ParameterEstimator ->{"MaximumLikelihood"}] 
GammaDistribution[2.112963149995775`, 0.0010189949208080507`]
```

Comment: Start here: [`ParameterEstimator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParameterEstimator.html). Also, include any code you have so far.

Comment: Yes, Gamma-distribution and scale parameter in particular. I used `ParameterEstimator`, but it only estimates the parameter, not the "accuracy" of this parameter.

Comment: I've just added the code

Comment: Can you define this "accuracy" for us? Or point to the definition somewhere?

Comment: It is a second derivative of the log likelihood with respect to scale parameter for example.

Comment: In item 1 you have "the right censored sample".  What value is used for the censoring?  In other words, are you wanting to determine the effect (change in bias, increase in variance, etc.) of right censoring on the maximum likelihood estimates for a gamma distribution?